Finding if an ideal is the radical of another one
Let's suppose we have, in the ring $\mathbb{Z} [x,y,z,w,v]$, the following polynomials:
$f=xw-yz$,
$g=x^2z-y^3$,
$h=yw^2-z^3$,
$k=xz^2-y^2w$.
The question is to prove that $I=(f,g,h,k)$ is the radical ideal of $J=(f,g,h)$.
I tried several things to no avail: by imposing $x>y>z>w$ I tried to divide $k^2$ by $J$, but since I don't know whether $f,g,h$ is a Grobner base I stopped since having the residual being non zero wouldn't have said anything about it (also, the residual is not zero in this case). I then remembered that if $J$ is primary, the radical is the smallest prime who contains it. But checking that $J$ is primary seems like hell honestly. Since those are not simple polynomials, checking if any power of $k$ is contained in $J$ seems crazy. I could use some kind of software to find a Grobner base of $J$, but I'd like to do it by my own hand, and since my professor didn't explain how to find Grobner bases, I don't think it's the intended method to solve the exercise. I asked this question before and got this hint: $k^2 = z^3*g + y^3*h -2y^2z^2*f$, so $I$ is surely contained in the radical, and $I^2 \subseteq J \subseteq I$. So maybe it would be helpful to be able to prove $I$ is prime, but again I feel like I'm missing something blatantly obvious that makes the question easier.
Am I comitting some judgement errors here? How do I prove the thesis? Can anybody help? Thank you in advance.

Here is a suggestion (which I think is hard to come up with on your own without having seen something similar). Consider the ring map $$\begin{aligned}
\varphi\colon \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z,w,v] &\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[s,t,v]\
x &\longmapsto s^4\
y &\longmapsto s^3t\
z &\longmapsto st^3\
w &\longmapsto t^4\
v &\longmapsto v
\end{aligned}$$
Since the image of $\varphi$ is a domain, we know that $\ker(\varphi)$ is prime. To show that $I$ is prime, it therefore suffices to show that $I = \ker(\varphi)$. This is still pretty difficult, but doable by hand.

I can confirm I've never seen something similar, but your reasoning makes sense. I guess the complicated part is showing that a polynomial in $ker(\phi)$ is a linear combination of $f,g,h,k$... And by proving $I$ is prime, I think we're done since $\sqrt{I^2} \subseteq \sqrt{J} \subseteq \sqrt{I}$ and if $I$ is prime, the radicals are equal to $I$ and we're done, right? I'll give it a try and let you know, but for now thanks a lot!
